# MySQL Workbench Loses Saved Connections

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I've been using MySQL Workbench as my go-to management application for quite some time. However, recently (namely, in my most recent install), it will every so often lose the saved connections I've put in. It doesn't happen every time, but sometimes, when I open it up, there won't be any saved connections and I have to re-enter them.

Does anyone know of a way to fix this? The only thing I've been able to find are the release notes, which claim to have fixed this issue over a year ago (ironically, I never had an issue with that until recently).

I'm currently running Lubuntu 11.04 64bit.

Answer (score 1):

Did you get the very, very latest?

The latest stable build ([here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/5.0.html)) is 5.1.19.  However, the bug fix has been put in place for 5.2.21 (per [here](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=55484)).

The absolute latest version available is 5.2.34, which should have the bug fix.  However, that's not the latest *stable* version; it's just the latest generally available (GA) version.  (It's available [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/5.2.html#downloads), for what it's worth.)

---

**Edit**

---

Since you have the latest version (with the alleged bug fix), I would [report this](http://bugs.mysql.com/report.php) as a new bug.

My only advice... Try to figure out if there is an exact sequence of steps that you can perform to make this happen every time.  Then give them all the information you can (including the version number you're using).

Comment: I have 5.2.34, which is supposed to not have the bug (as you mentioned, but I needed more characters).

Answer (score -1):

I'm using 5.2.45 and have recently experienced this bug on multiple installations. Stored connections do not persist. Previously, I did not experience this in a past version.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! This site (and the others in the SE family) are not forums, but rather Q&A sites. The answer section is to be used *only* for answers, and not for discussion. [Please see the FAQ for information on what's expected here.](http://dba.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion)